# How to parse string HTML using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string

I have response data in form of:

```
'<b>How can I waive the underage fee?</b><br>\n You … have marked your age correctly before searching.'
```

So the question is, how can I use that data in React Component?
I have to use it between two divs. Given data is string form of html syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display this html content in a component, you can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` this way:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:data}} />
```

This will inject the HTML in you DOM. As mentioned in the doc, be aware of risks involved with injecting some unknown HMTL.

Source : https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Also i need to discard first element, i.e. <b></b> tag. Can you help it about too??

Comment: You should write a small parse function for this. Feel free to open a new question on SO if you need some help on that.

Comment: Thanks for your responses but my boss is not happy with this method, also we do not use jquery in the project. Do you guys have different advice? In fact, my boss doesnt want that solution because we cannot directly inject style to injected html. For ex, I cannot make list-style:none; with this method.

Comment: Please open another specific question for this case.